# Using Self Hosted font in Material UI with Next JS

Tags: next.js, fonts, material-ui

I don't understand why this is so difficult... I have a font in my fonts folder and I want to use it in my Material UI theme. I am using Next JS and Material UI. When I follow the  documentation it says I do not have the proper loaders and then I go back to square one.

My Theme looks like this:

```
import HelveticaNeue from "./public/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff2"

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily:
      "HelveticaNeue",
components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url(/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }
      `,
```

there must be an easier way I have to be missing something